# How to get the item that has the highest number of occurence in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products as shown below:

```
id    name    quantity
1     shoe       2
2     pen        1
3     shoe       1
4     glass      3
5     pen        4
6     shoe       2
```

I want to get the item that occurs more in the table and the number of rows it occupies or the how many times it is repeated in the table.
In the case of the above table, `shoe` occurs the highest number of times i.e. 3 times. I need the mysql query that can permit me to do this (return 3 in the above case).

Please take performance into consideration, since this query will be perform over a table having about 10 million records. Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any effort at this?  This is a VERY simple `GROUP BY` (aggregation) query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name,count(*) FROM products GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 1
```

This may work

Answer (score 0):

A basic `GROUP BY` will do:

```
select top 1 name, count(name), sum(quantity)
from XX
group by name
order by count(name) desc
```